# 'Listening in' to a question

Tags: feature-request, questions, request-for-information, recent-activity

Maybe I'm missing here something... I believe others have had this issue before, too. So here it is: I can't find a way of following or 'listening in' to questions I am interested in. I'd like to get notified, if there is fresh activity going on somewhere (obviously I'm not talking about my own questions), without having to either scroll the active questions list up and down or to keep a tab open for every question I'd like to hear from. It's probably more akin to the news feed on FaceBook for instance. Is this really a missing feature? If so, will there be anything like that around soon?

**EDIT**: I am aware of the `favorites` feature, but that's not really what I want. I'd like to see immediately which particular question has new activity. I prefer to use `favorites` to mark questions that are - well favorites... questions that are interesting, special, useful, etc. or have answers I might want to look up later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every question has its own [RSS feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). At the very least, the following link should appear at the end of each page:

[image: Screencap of the RSS button.]

There are hundreds of applications that will notify you when there is new activity in a given feed. The [Safari browser](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html#rss), for example, does this out of the box. [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/) is a popular web-based option. If you want more suggestions, just ask!

Comment: Oh, cool! `:)` Took me a few minutes to find it though... That nasty little button likes to hide in the bottom right corner of the page! `:D`

Comment: @CountZero: For RSS I would recommend Stack2RSS, cf. [RSS feed for New questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/rss-feed-for-new-questions), esp. my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can make the question a favorite by clicking the star below the voting arrows. If you then go to your profile page you will see a 'favorites' tab with a red number showing how many of them changed since you last watch the favorites page:

[image]

That's not the same as a direct notification, because you have to check your own profile to see it, but still good enough, IMHO.

Comment: I was aware of that feature. I am looking rather for a direct notification, so I can see immediately which question has recent activity. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: @CountZero: In such cases its good if it is mentioned in the question that you are aware about a similar feature and state that it's not what you are looking for.

Comment: I edited my question.